# $(...parent()).html() didn't capture the textarea content

Tags: jquery, textarea, clone

I am generating user control according to search result. And allowing to change text inside of textarea (picture or video description)

[image]

aaaaaa is default text to change. User can change textarea and when user clicked on EKLE (ADD) button,

i am cloning DIV element that contains image, span, textarea elements and their value. When clicked on EKLE(ADD) button, i am taking EKLE button's parent and appending to result div. But  i can't see the textarea content .
[image]

```
// this function is cloning the one result div which is clicked on it and appending the result
function f_ResimSecildi_Ekle(divEklenecek) {

    $(divEklenecek).clone().prependTo("#divEklenenResimler").hide().fadeIn("slow");
    $("#divEklenenResimler input[id*=btnEkleResim_]").remove();
    $("#divEklenenResimler input[id*=btnKaldirResim_]").removeAttr("style").show();
    $("#btnHaberResimleriYap").removeAttr("disabled");        
}
```

[image]

Comment: Pictures in your question don't work, at least not at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
function f_ResimSecildi_Ekle(divEklenecek) {
    $(divEklenecek).clone().val(
        $(divEklenecek).val()
    ).prependTo("#divEklenenResimler").hide().fadeIn("slow");
    $("#divEklenenResimler input[id*=btnEkleResim_]").remove();
    $("#divEklenenResimler input[id*=btnKaldirResim_]").removeAttr("style").show();
    $("#btnHaberResimleriYap").removeAttr("disabled");        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, here is the part where you realize when you clone an input control, the user-data isn't copied as well. Why don't you try using the `val()` method on the original `textarea` and setting on the cloned object (again using the `val()` method!).

Answer (score -1):

You must use `.val()` method.